# Java derivating expression to expression and equations

Tags: java, parsing, equation, solver, derivative

I am trying to solve 2 problems.
I am doing app which should solve math problems.

I have expression parser based on grammar and AST but the main problem is that I need to create a derivate expression from expressions with unknown variable here is the example.

function :  `(x1)^2+4(x2)^2-2x1-4x2`

```
x1 = 5+α
x2 = 2
```

I need derivate `(5+α)^2+4(2)^2-2*(5+α)-4*2  === 2*(5+α)+8 =>` as String result

and then from `2*(5+α)+8 count α =?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the AST with mathematical rules. For better readability I use x instead of x1.

To find f'(x), we need a rule that matches all expression of the form x^n and replaces it with n*x^(n-1).

Now you can replace the variables with the actual values. To find the simpler representation, you have to evaluate and transform the AST term. As expressions you have variables (e.g. a), numbers and operations (e.g. sum product, ...). The best way to visualize this is drawing trees.

examples for simple expressions with numeric values:

- prod(num(2), num(3)) => num(6)

examples for expressions with variables:

- sum(prod(var(a),num(2)), prod(var(a),num(3))) => prod(var(a), sum(num(2),num(3)))

Here you have to think which transformations you want to do... The rules you define on the AST will determine how the term will look in the end.

Comment: I found out that i have another problem . I can t count that expresions cuz i have X with i can t initialize. It means i will have like 10+x+2*3^2 .
Result should be 28+x . But don t know how to evaluate that because i can t initialize x variable . That is unknown with i will have to count

Anyway thank you for help

Comment: Can you show the object model of the AST? 10+x+2*3^2 is just a String - how does the AST look for this expression?

Comment: if i assigend x= 1 or x = value then its counter as double so it gives me value of expresion.
When x = (a+1) then its error because a is not initialized.
This should be separated to terms : (10,x,2*3^2)
this is counted so (10,x,18)
But AdditionNode is value += term.getValue(); so it can t count 10+(a+1)+18

Comment: Agree with @hotzenplotz, you have to code transforms to modify your expression ASTs.  With the machinery you likely have, you'll have to code these transformations procedurally.   I can't help you with this in an interesting way (it is *just* coding),  but if you want to see what rewrite rules you should apply to your trees, check out http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html

Answer (score 0):

With the Java [Symja project](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) you can solve your problem with the following steps:

```
import org.matheclipse.core.convert.VariablesSet;
import org.matheclipse.core.eval.ExprEvaluator;
import org.matheclipse.core.expression.F;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IAST;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.SyntaxError;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.math.MathException;

public class SolveSO43024172 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExprEvaluator util = new ExprEvaluator();
            IExpr expr = util.evaluate("(x1)^2+4*(x2)^2-2*x1-4*x2");
            System.out.println(expr.toString());

            // determine the variables used in the expression
            IAST variableList = VariablesSet.getVariables(expr);
            System.out.println(variableList.toString());

            IExpr a = util.evaluate("a");
            IExpr x1 = util.evaluate("x1");
            IExpr x2 = util.evaluate("x2");
            IExpr x1Substitute = util.evaluate("5+a");
            IExpr x2Substitute = util.evaluate("2");

            IAST astRules = F.List(F.Rule(x1, x1Substitute), F.Rule(x2, x2Substitute));
            // {x1->5+a,x2->2}
            System.out.println(astRules.toString());

            IExpr replacedExpr = expr.replaceAll(astRules);
            // -2*(5+a)+(5+a)^2+(-4)*2+4*2^2
            System.out.println(replacedExpr.toString());
            // 8+(5+a)^2-2*(5+a)
            replacedExpr = util.evaluate(replacedExpr);
            System.out.println(replacedExpr.toString());

            // replacedExpr = util.evaluate(F.ExpandAll(replacedExpr));
            // 23+8*a+a^2
            // System.out.println(replacedExpr.toString());

            IExpr derivedExpr = util.evaluate(F.D(replacedExpr, a));
            // -2+2*(5+a)
            System.out.println(derivedExpr.toString());

            IExpr equation = F.Equal(derivedExpr, F.C0);
            // -2+2*(5+a)==0
            System.out.println(equation.toString());

            IExpr solvedEquation = util.evaluate(F.Solve(equation, a));
            // {{a->-4}}
            System.out.println(solvedEquation.toString());

        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            // catch Symja parser errors here
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MathException me) {
            // catch Symja math errors here
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final StackOverflowError soe) {
            System.out.println(soe.getMessage());
        } catch (final OutOfMemoryError oome) {
            System.out.println(oome.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could i have some Message that there is not defined variable ? when i have calculated expresions but x1 is not defined . How could i get those message handled ?

Comment: Edited my example: // determine the variables used in the expression
            IAST variableList = VariablesSet.getVariables(expr);
            System.out.println(variableList.toString());

Comment: Thank you but that is not working . Method getVariables(expr) is no recognized

Comment: Sorry I forgot the import line: import org.matheclipse.core.convert.VariablesSet;

Comment: Yes that i thought too but i just could not find that import. Thank you . If i can i have 1 more question . After this : IExpr solvedEquation = util.evaluate(F.Solve(equation, b)); i get result . But i need it as doble value for using . Result is like : String = b->{10/9}. Can you help me with thise as well please ?

Comment: 1 last problem. Is there any possibility to set rounding number while equation is counting ? Like solving equation with double with for example 4 numbers  = 18/5 = 3.599999999999 => 3.6

Comment: I am sorry for so many questions ,this 1 is really last . I got after derivation expression :  -115 = 0 there was no unknown value so result is 0==0. Is that hadled somehow ??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but i can t use symja . It has to be hand writen.

Still have troubles to make it .

Problem is that my AST after parsing is returning value so i need put expression with numbers only but i have to use variables witch i don t know :

like : -(30*x1+20*x2)+3/5*(3*x1^2+2*x2^2+(x1+x2)^2).

x1  = 2 , x2 = 2+a

Solution is derivative expresion and from expresion count a